# Elegant way to chain Scala partial functions

Tags: scala

I am looking for an elegant way to chain partial functions that derive from a common base type. The idea is that each partial function handles a type so they become easy to compose for different types and have a common catch-all if the chained partial function is undefined:

```
trait Message
trait SysMessage extends Message
trait UserMessage extends Message

case class TextSysMessage(m: String) extends SysMessage
case class TextUserMessage(m: String) extends UserMessage

class Test {

  type MessagePF = scala.PartialFunction[Message, String]
  type SysMessagePF = scala.PartialFunction[SysMessage, String]
  type UserMessagePF = scala.PartialFunction[UserMessage, String]

  def getSysMessage: SysMessagePF = {
    case sm: TextSysMessage ⇒ s"System message: ${sm.m}"
  }

  def getUserMessage: UserMessagePF = {
    case um: TextUserMessage ⇒ s"User message: ${um.m}"
  }

  def * : MessagePF = {
    case m ⇒ s"Unknown message: $m"
  }

  // Chained partials fails because `m` is a SysMessage with UserMessage
  def handler(m: Message): String = (getSysMessage orElse getUserMessage orElse *)(m)
}
```

Clearly, this approach does not compile. I can get around this by nested pattern matching like this

```
def getSysMessage: MessagePF = {
  case m: SysMessage ⇒ m match {
    case sm: TextSysMessage ⇒ s"System message: ${sm.m}"
  }
}
```

but then I loose the capability of handling unknown messages in a catch all. Is there some elegant way to achieve this goal?

Comment: Why not define each `PartialFunction` with `Message` as input type?

Comment: That is essentially  plan B....

Comment: But how can you even expect a partial function that takes concrete subtype to work with arbitrary `Message`? Something like `def handler(m: Message): String = (getSysMessage)(m)` won't work either.

Comment: Not expecting this. Just looking for an elegant way to achieve something similar.

Comment: The whole purpose of `getSysMessage` and `getUserMessage` is to try match some `Message` on concrete type. If you decide that this partial function must take this concrete subtype of `Message` then you already know (statically) that it's of this kind, which defeats the point why these methods exist.

Comment: Point taken (this is how I have built my actual implementation). @Odomontois has something that I will play with. Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As addition to @adamwy + Hongxu Chen's answer, you can define your very own combinator, which involves implicit parameters, so enforces slightly different application syntax

```
implicit class PartFuncOps[A: ClassTag, B](pf: PartialFunction[A, B]) {
  def or[D >: A, C <: D : ClassTag](other: PartialFunction[C, B]): PartialFunction[D, B] = {
    case a: A if pf.isDefinedAt(a) ⇒ pf(a)
    case c: C if other.isDefinedAt(c) ⇒ other(c)
  }
}
```

Now you can write

```
def combine = getSysMessage or getUserMessage or *
def handler(m: Message): String = combine(m)
```

Or

```
def handler(m: Message): String = (getSysMessage or getUserMessage or *).apply(m)
```

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by @adamwy, you can change the partial function type to be:

```
type MessagePF = scala.PartialFunction[Message, String]
type SysMessagePF = scala.PartialFunction[Message, String]
type UserMessagePF = scala.PartialFunction[Message, String]
```

Comment: Or just use one type for all.